# How to edit pdf using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, plugins

I have a requirement to upload a pdf file and edit the same pdf file in the flutter app how to achieve this we have any packages are there to edit existing pdf? please help me with this difficulty.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a package that has a great rating and appears that it can be used for what  you are wanting.

> The Flutter PDF is a library written natively in Dart for creating,
> reading, editing, and securing PDF files in Android, iOS, and web
> platforms.

[The Flutter PDF](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf)

Another note is; if you are not familiar with https://pub.dev/ then it is the perfect place (and the proper place) to find and use packages to build Dart and Flutter apps.

Anytime you are looking for a package or thinking someone may have already done the work like: QR scanner, color spinners, splashsreens etc then just search the site.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the very quick replay, but how to use it if u have any examples it will very help full.
Thank You .

Comment: The link I sent you has documentation that shows and describes how to use it. If you are wanting help implementing the actual pack and using it; I could try and record a small video using it. However, that is more than what you asked for in your question :).

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your question, but if you just need to create pdf's from scratch, you could use [pdf package from pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf).

This package has widgets for building pdfs that are similar in functionality to flutter widgets.
See how `pw` is used in the pub.dev examples.